# How to let users upload directly to google datastorage from google app engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, codeigniter-3

I am having trouble to let users upload files to my php program running on google app engine. I am trying to follow [this google manual](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload).

I am working with codeIgniter 3, I set up following controllers:

Projecteditor.php:

```
public function index( $cluster_id )
{
    if( $this->require_min_level( 1 ) )
    {
        $project_access_lvl = $this->check_access_lvl( $cluster_id );
        if( $project_access_lvl >= 0 )
        {
            // Upload files to Google Cloud Storage
            $my_bucket = 'THE_ID.appspot.com';
            $options = ['gs_bucket_name' => $my_bucket]; //todo app id
            $upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/main.php/upload/handler', $options);
            $view_data['upload_url'] = $upload_url;

            // Display webpage
            $cluster = $this->cluster_model->get_cluster_by_id( $cluster_id )[0];
            $project = $this->project_model->get_projects( $cluster['projecten_project_id'])[0];

            $view_data['fase_details'] = $this->get_fase_details( $cluster['fase'] );
            $view_data['project_name'] = $project['naam'];

            echo $this->load->view('templates/header', '', TRUE);
            echo $this->load->view('projecteditor/index', ( isset( $view_data ) ) ? $view_data : '', TRUE );
            echo $this->load->view('templates/footer', '', TRUE);
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO syslog
        }
    }
}
```

Upload.php:

```
public function handler()
{
    $my_bucket = 'THE_ID.appspot.com';
    # [START move_uploaded_file]
    $file_name = $_FILES['uploaded_files']['name'];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['uploaded_files']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "gs://${my_bucket}/${file_name}.txt");
    # [END move_uploaded_file]
    return sprintf('Your file "%s" has been uploaded.', $file_name);
}
```

Of course I replaced THE_ID with the correct bucket id.

The form inside the view that corresponds with the Projecteditor controller:

```
<?php
    echo form_open($upload_url, array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
?>
<div class="col-lg-12">
     <div id="my-dropzone" class="dropzone" action="#">
         <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="bold">Upload</span></button>              
         </div>
     </div></div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

The files are uploaded by using the jQuery dropbox plugin.
I suspect I entered the wrong relative url inside CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl but I cannot really find out what I am supposed to enter as the relative URL.

the absolute urls for both controllers are:

Projecteditor.php:
https://example.com/projecteditor/index/SOME_VARIABLE

Upload.php:
https://example.com/main.php/upload/handler

When my code executes I get a post to the Projecteditor.php but not to the Upload.php also the datastore bucket stays empty.

I also used [this source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/storage/app.php) about the google storage bucket.

Please let me know if I did something wrong or there are alternative ways (easier ways) to store my data.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was a misconfiguration in the jQuery dropbox plugin that prevented the files from being uploaded, on the PHP side everything worked fine.